# error on create jqgrid local

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm try create a jqgrid local:

This is my code:

```
  var mydata=
        [
         {example1:"example1", example2:"2007-10-01",example3:"example "},
        ]
    $("#grid_plan_accion").jqGrid({
        datatype:'local',
        data: mydata,
        colNames:['example1', 'example2',' example3'],
        colModel:[
            { label: 'example1', name: 'example1', width: 20, sorttype:"string", editable:true},
            { label: 'example2', name: 'example2', width: 20, sorttype:"string", editable:true},
            { label: 'example3', name: 'example3', width: 20, sorttype:"string", editable:true},
        ],
        rowNum:10,
        pager: '#pager_plan_accion',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        shrinkToFit: true,

    });
```

i dont get errors, only dont show the jqgrid, i dont know what is my error?, please any suggest or link for create an example, thanks

Comment: which version of jqgrid you are using?

Comment: thanks my version is 5.2

Comment: Please check my answer, data is showing

Comment: @Tegito123: Your code could be improved, but the existing one is correct and should work (see https://jsfiddle.net/3hv6k1fy/ with exact copy of your code). You should search the problem in files, which you included, verify that `<table id="grid_plan_accion"></table>` exists, one should verify that the code is executed after document will be ready and so on. Usage of `addRowData` in the loop is very bad. One should use `data: mydata`.

Comment: @Oleg thanks is correct your answer, but know im try set editable rows, but  I do not get it

Comment: i set editable:true on colModel, and editurl: 'clientArray', but dont get it

Comment: @Tegito123: First of all, you have to decide, which from 3 editing modes you want to use: inline editing, form editing or cell editing. Then you should either start `editRow` or `editGridRow` manually inside of `onSelectRow` or inside of `ondblClickRow` or alternatively you can just add a column with `formatter: "actions"` or call `navGrid` or/and `inlineNav` to have editing buttons inside of the pager. See for example the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/su7ebs65/, where some additional features of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
        var mydata =
            [
                { example1: "example1", example2: "2007-10-01", example3: "example " },
            ]

        $("#grid_plan_accion").jqGrid({
            datatype: 'json',
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ['example1', 'example2', ' example3'],
            colModel: [
                { label: 'example1', name: 'example1', width: 150, sorttype: "string", editable: true },
                { label: 'example2', name: 'example2', width: 150, sorttype: "string", editable: true },
                { label: 'example3', name: 'example3', width: 150, sorttype: "string", editable: true },
            ],
            rowNum: 10,
            height: 250,
            shrinkToFit: true,

        });
        for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++)
            jQuery("#grid_plan_accion").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<table id="grid_plan_accion"></table>
```